# catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS ...) vs. find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)

Tags: ros, catkin, catkin-package, find-package, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Let's say I have a package `A` that depends on `sensor_msgs`. I have to add `sensor_msgs` to both

> find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS sensor_msgs)

> catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS sensor_msgs)

What is the difference between the two? What purpose do each of them solve? For instance, I noticed that `message_generation` has to be in the `find_package` call while the `message_runtime` has to be in `catkin_package` call. Why are they not in both?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261002/catkin_package(catkin_depends-...)-vs.-find_package(catkin-required-components-...)/) by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1133 on 2017-05-03

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`find_package()` finds dependencies for this package.

`catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS)` declares dependencies for packages that depend on this package.

For example: `message_generation` is needed by this package to build messages, while `message_runtime` is needed by dependent packages to use the already generated messages.

---

Originally posted by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) with karma: 1416 on 2017-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7